# get index of all occurences of value from inside double 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

First of all feel free to edit title if it isn't precise enough.

JS is completly not my territory.
Im trying to write this custom JS callback and, aside of the index-grabing line, it does what i require.
However since im already inside a double for-loop i have no idea how to push correct

( by correct I mean: the indexes under which each occurence of value present in 'active holder' var resided before pushing to 'partial_data' var)

indexes into indexes var. As it looks now, it will only return index of first occurence.

```
var full_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'h']
var partial_data = []
var active_holder = ['a', 'g']
var indexes = []

for (j = 0; j < full_data.length; j++) {

    for (z = 0; z < active_holder.length; z++) {

        if (active_holder[z].includes(full_data[j])) {

            indexes.push(full_data.indexOf(full_data[j]));
            partial_data.push(full_data[j]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(partial_data) // * ['a', 'a', 'g', 'g'] // 
console.log(indexes) // * [0, 0, 5, 5] // WRONG, should be 0,4,5,6 or something along
```

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: One suggestion: declare `j` and `z` with `var` or `let`

Comment: also your code *already has* the index: it's the value of `j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are again calling `indexOf` while `push()`. You should just `push()` `j`.

> **indexOf**: returns the index for **first occurence** of value in array

```js
var full_data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'h']
var partial_data = []
var active_holder = ['a', 'g']
var indexes = []

for (j = 0; j < full_data.length; j++) {

    for (z = 0; z < active_holder.length; z++) {

        if (active_holder[z].includes(full_data[j])) {

            indexes.push(j);
            partial_data.push(full_data[j]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(partial_data) // * ['a', 'a', 'g', 'g'] // 
console.log(indexes) // * [0, 0, 5, 5] // WRONG, should be 0,4,5,6 or something along
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const fullData = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'h']
const active = ['a', 'g']

let {partial, index} = fullData.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
  if( active.includes(inp) ){
    op.partial.push(inp)
    op.index.push(index)
  }
  return op
},{partial:[],index:[]})

console.log(partial)
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method and return one object with both indexes and partial data.

```js
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'h']
var active = ['a', 'g']

const {
  index,
  partial
} = data.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  if (active.includes(e)) {
    r.index.push(i)
    r.partial.push(e)
  }
  return r
}, {
  index: [],
  partial: []
})


console.log(index)
console.log(partial)
```